# Assign user permission in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

Is there anyway using query that I can assign permissions to user in a SQL Server database?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GRANT exists even for MsSQL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx

Comment: USE Test
CREATE USER MyUser FOR LOGIN MyUser
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'MyUser'

Answer (score 2):

You can use the T-Sql Statement `GRANT`

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx) you can find general documentation on `GRANT`

While [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173848.aspx) you can find the page specific for user privlege